# Form not validating before Submit (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form written in JavaScript that works correctly when I submit. However, there is one conditional which I would like to be validated before the user hits the submit button. If the user chooses "None" on the dropdown menu, I want the other dropdown menu and textbox to be disabled before the user tries to submit. This is what I've done so far, but nothing seems to happen everytime I choose "None":

```
<form name="my_form" onsubmit="return submit()" action="/test" method="post">

<select id="month">
   <option value="None">None</option>
   <option value="0">January</option>
   <option value="1">February</option>
   <option value="2">March</option>
   <option value="3">April</option>
   <option value="4">May</option>
   <option value="5">June</option>
   <option value="6">July</option>
   <option value="7">August</option>
   <option value="8">September</option>
   <option value="9">October</option>
   <option value="10">November</option>
   <option value="11">December</option>
  </select>


<select id="day">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="7">7</option>
   <option value="8">8</option>
   <option value="9">9</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="year" placeholder="Year" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>

<script>


function submit(){

var get_month_value = month.options[month.selectedIndex].text;

if(get_month_value == "None"){
      document.getElementById("year").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("day").disabled = true;
      return false;
    }


    else if(year == ""){
      alert("Year must be filled out");
      return false;
    }

</script>
```

Where am I going wrong with this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Don't name your functions after events. You also have no element with the ID of year.

Comment: is it going in `submit` function or not

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code has the following errors:-

1. First of all you can't give your function the name `submit` in your form attribute.
2. You are missing `}` at the end of your function.
3. Your Input Text should have `id=year` not `name`.
4. Month is not defined.
5. year is not defined.

**Change**
these lines in your HTML:-

```
<form name="my_form" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="/test" method="post">
<input type="text" id="year" placeholder="Year" />
```

Javascript:-

```
function validateForm(){
    var month = document.getElementById('month');
    var year = document.getElementById('year').value;
    var get_month_value = month.options[month.selectedIndex].text;

    if(get_month_value == "None"){
          document.getElementById("year").disabled = true;
          document.getElementById("day").disabled = true;
          return false;
        }


        else if(year == ""){
          alert("Year must be filled out");
          return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give form an `ID` and remove the `onsubmit` function:

```
<form id="my_form" name="my_form" action="/test" method="post">
```

Place the submit button outside the form and add the `onclick` function:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submit();" />
```

Give `year` text field an `ID`:

```
<input type="text" id="year" name="year" placeholder="Year" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
function submit() {
    var select = document.getElementById("month");
    var get_month_value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    var year = document.getElementById('year').value;

    if ((get_month_value == "None") || (year == "")) {
        alert("Please fill out the required fields");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("my_form").submit();
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KEsda/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 Date picker with "**required**" attribute(works):

```
<form id="dateForm" name="dateForm" action="/test" method="post">
  Date: <input type="date" name="date" required />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

No need for JScript and html for dropdowns.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/komanchero/f4h2U/1/)**